# Finding corresponding PyNaCL functions in libsodium (C#)

Tags: python, c#, cryptography, libsodium, pynacl

I am using a python rest server (which I found here: https://github.com/xxblx/tornado-app-template) that supports access tokens and lets a client sign the access tokens.
The repository contains a python client that creates a SigningKey on the client side. The provided code shows how to create the required keys and hashes required to create a user that is later able to sign tokens.

```
    # client.py (Line 71 ff)
    def signup_user(self):
        verify_key = self.signing_key.verify_key
        verify_key_hex = verify_key.encode(encoder=nacl.encoding.HexEncoder)

        # Encrypt signing key
        signing_key_bytes = self.signing_key.encode()
        password_hash = nacl.hash.blake2b(self.password.encode(),
                                      encoder=nacl.encoding.HexEncoder)

        salt = nacl.utils.random(nacl.pwhash.argon2i.SALTBYTES)
        ops = nacl.pwhash.argon2i.OPSLIMIT_SENSITIVE
        mem = nacl.pwhash.argon2i.MEMLIMIT_SENSITIVE
        key = nacl.pwhash.argon2i.kdf(nacl.secret.SecretBox.KEY_SIZE,
                                  password_hash, salt, opslimit=ops,
                                  memlimit=mem)

        box = nacl.secret.SecretBox(key)
        nonce = nacl.utils.random(nacl.secret.SecretBox.NONCE_SIZE)
        encrypted_signing_key = box.encrypt(signing_key_bytes, nonce)

        encrypted_signing_key = base64.encodebytes(encrypted_signing_key)
        salt = base64.encodebytes(salt)

        # Send data to server
        data = {
            'username': self.username, 'password': self.password,
            'privkey': encrypted_signing_key.decode(),
            'pubkey_hex': verify_key_hex.decode(),
            'privkey_salt': salt.decode(),
            'privkey_opslimit': ops, 'privkey_memlimit': mem
        }
```

I want to write a C# client that can generate a SigningKey and is capable of signing the tokens in the same way. I am using libsodium 1.0.16 for my client and I am having trouble creating an equivalent keypair, not to mention finding the corresponding function for creating the *password_hash* or the *key* in the above code. I am not even sure which functions to use for the key creation. From my small understanding of crypto, I assume that it should be possible. Any help regarding finding the correct *libsodium* function for the above used *nacl* functions (nacl.hash.blake2b, nacl.secret.SecretBox(key), nacl.pwhash.argon2i.kdf(...), etc) or a hint for creating an equivalent SigningKey would be great.

```
    # python SigningKey creation using PyNaCl
    _signing_key = nacl.signing.SigningKey.generate()

    # --> Line 158 signing.py from nacl 
    # under the hood SigningKey.generate() uses 
    public_key, secret_key = nacl.bindings.crypto_sign_seed_keypair(seed)
```

My approach in C# using libsodium to create this public and secret key looks like this:

```
    pk = new byte[64];
    sk = new byte[64];
    byte[] seed = unity.libsodium.StreamEncryption.GetRandomBytes(32);
    unity.libsodium.NativeLibsodium.crypto_sign_seed_keypair(pk, sk, seed);
```

Is this a good start?

Comment: Can it be any Libsodium port for C#, or does it have to be a specific library?

Comment: @Topaco I am currently using a libsodium wrapping for unity (provided here https://github.com/netpyoung/unity.libsodium). The [NativeLibsodium.cs file](https://github.com/netpyoung/unity.libsodium/blob/master/unity_project/Assets/unity.libsodium/NativeLibsodium.cs) shows all the sodium functions that i can use.

Comment: Ah OK, I'm not familiar with Unity so unfortunately I can't help. You should make this limitation clearer in your question, since there are several Libsodium ports for C#.

Comment: Oh, by libsodium ports you mean different versions - (my bad). I use a wrapping of libsodium 1.0.16 - the wrapping does not use any particular Unity functionality.
Yeah, i will add the port to the question.

Comment: No, I don't mean the version, but the port/wrapper. There are several Libsodium ports for C#, e.g. libsodium-net, NSec, NitraLibSodium etc. see [here](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/bindings_for_other_languages#bindings-programming-languages). unity.libsodium seems to be another port. So my question is whether any port will do, e.g. libsodium-net, or whether it has to be unity.libsodium.